# Unable to automate Hybrid Android mobile app using appium

Tags: appium-android

I want to automate test a basic Hybrid Mobile Application running in Android.I am able to launch the app in emulator but not able to enter the text in the login screen.

Getting error as

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   io.appium.java_client.NoSuchContextException: An unknown server-side
>   error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No
>   Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '53.0.2785'. See
>   https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md
>   for more details. "

Please help me resolving this!!!!!

Comment: If I check in command prompt for devices:C:\Users\admin>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

Comment: Environment:
Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue:
1.8.2
Desktop OS/version used to run Appium:
Win 10
Mobile platform/version under test:
Android 7.1.1
Real device or emulator/simulator:
emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you see chromedriver.exe change log you will get the version you require for hybrid app automation. The browser used in your device have versin 53+
2. See this url http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads [check ChromeDriver 2.24 details] it says it supports browser with version 53+. Get this exe from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/
3. How to connect with Appium - 
   If you are using appium desktop, it gets installed as windows application in program files folder. Now location of chromedriver.exe it uses is as mentioned below.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\chromedriver.exe [This location may be bit different in your case]

4. Replace above location chromedriver from downloaded chromedriver.exe(from step2)

Note - Ideally automation should work without throwing exception. Incase still it doesn't work then try 1+ or 1- version of 2.24

Comment: Thanks Amith. It's working now.  Downloaded "ChromeDriver 2.24.417431".

Comment: @RanjitJain - Please accept the answer as it will be beneficial for others too.

Answer (score 0):

You got everything you need in exception message:
Go here https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md 
and read explanation on compatibility.

`No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '53.0.2785'`

Appium was not able to get chromedriver for your emulator that have **Chrome 53.0.2785**

So the first solution is to get [Chromedriver v2.26](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.26/) and add absolute path to binary as **chromedriverExecutable** capability:
1) download `chromedriver_win32.zip` from the link above and unzip
2) in your code add capability with the path to chromedriver.exe:

`DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
...
caps.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "/abs/path/to/chromedriver.exe")`

If you get new emulator, first check what browser version is preinstalled and try to upgrade.

Comment: Since I am new to Mobile App Automation, please suggest me on how to declare "add absolute path to binary as chromedriverExecutable capability."        
Upon placing the appropriate ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 v, selenium console still displays exception.Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '59.0.3071'.

Comment: I updated the answer. Go and read http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/ to understand more about Appium